# How to insert a record from Access table into a mysql table

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I am coding in Access VBA to insert into a Mysql table with records from a table in Access. `myDSN` is a system DSN created in ODBC and it works.I tried the codes below with but it returned a runtime error (80040e14). Is it possible to refer to one table from a adodb connection and a table in Access in the same SQL string?

```
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Str_Sql As String

Call ODBCVari

Conn.Open "dsn=myDSN;uid=Username;pwd=Password"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn

Str_Sql = "insert into [dsn=myDSN;uid=Username;pwd=Password].Table_MySQL select * from Table_Access"

Conn.Execute Str_Sql
Conn.Close
```

Comment: You need two differenct connections. One to Access and one to MySql, And you shouldn't use anymore ADODB. There are better options in the NET world. Use the specific providers like OleDb for Access and the MySql connector for MySql

Comment: I am coding in Access VBA environment.

Comment: Then why did you post a question tagging it with VB.NET?

Comment: you can link the mysql table as linked table in Access and then do a normal `insert into mysqltable select * from accessTable` is it not an option? if you can't keep the table, after insert delete the linked table.